# Use of vertical ellipsis in matrix notation

Tags: matrices, notation

A matrix Q is defined as:

```
Q = [K⋮w]
```

K is another matrix and w is a vector - what does "⋮" mean in this instance?

Comment: Where did you see this?  If it was in some book, what book? Is this possibly the same notation as in [Matrix Notation: What does $A = [R | t]$  mean?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52905/matrix-notation-what-does-a-r-t-mean?rq=1)

Comment: Write down elements of K and w. as if K and w are kept side by side. That line is for concatenating two matrices.

Comment: It's from a Nature Genetics paper (page 28 of the supplementary information: [http://www.nature.com/ng/journal/v46/n2/full/ng.2876.html#supplementary-information])

@MJD: I think you're right, it is another way to write | (it is a concatenation)